# Errors in code generated with swagger codegen for typescript-angular

Tags: angular, swagger, swagger-codegen

I have used Swagger CodeGen to generate the API client for an Angular5 application.

I have generated the code using maven plugin configured as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>contracts</groupId>
    <artifactId>angular-contracts-api-client</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Angular Contracts API Client</name>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <description>Contracts API Java Client</description>
    <prerequisites>
        <maven>2.2.0</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <output>${project.basedir}</output>
                            <!-- specify the swagger yaml -->
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/../contracts-api-editor/api/swagger/swagger.yaml</inputSpec>

                            <language>typescript-angular</language>
                            <output>${project.basedir}/contracts-api</output>
                            <configOptions>
                                <ngVersion>5.1.1</ngVersion>
                                <npmName>angular-contracts-api</npmName>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <swagger-core-version>1.5.12</swagger-core-version>
        <maven-plugin-version>1.0.0</maven-plugin-version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

In the angular application, the package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "adf-cli-acs-template",
  "version": "2.1.0",
  "blueprint": "Content Services",
  "description": "ACS ADF Application with Angular CLI",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "nohup ng serve --host 0.0.0.0> exaricm-ui.log 2> exaricm-ui-err.log &",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@alfresco/adf-content-services": "2.1.0",
    "@alfresco/adf-core": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.8",
    "@angular/common": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/forms": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "5.1.1",
    "@mat-datetimepicker/core": "^1.0.1",
    "@mat-datetimepicker/moment": "^1.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "8.0.0",
    "alfresco-js-api": "2.0.0",
    "chart.js": "2.5.0",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "custom-event-polyfill": "0.3.0",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "minimatch": "3.0.4",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "moment-es6": "^1.0.0",
    "ng2-charts": "1.6.0",
    "pdfjs-dist": "1.5.404",
    "raphael": "2.2.7",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "require": "^2.4.20",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "0.0.29",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

The classes generated for the API contain several failing references of the namespace ng that is not available. For example:

```
constructor(protected $http: ng.IHttpService, protected $httpParamSerializer?: (d: any) => any, basePath?: string) {
    if (basePath !== undefined) {
        this.basePath = basePath;
    }
}
```

How can I make the namespace ng available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to use the latest version of the maven plugin (currently 2.3.1).
There are still some issues, but this has been fixed.